# Asp.Net MVC style routing in Django

Tags: asp.net-mvc, django

I've been programming in Asp.Net MVC for quite some time now and to expand a little bit beyond the .Net world I've recently began learning Python and Django. I am enjoying Django but one thing I am missing from Asp.Net MVC is the automatic routing from my urls to my controller actions.

In Asp.Net MVC I can build much of my application using this single default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",                                              // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
 );
```

In Django I've found myself adding an entry to urls.py for each view that I want to expose which leads to a lot more url patterns than I've become used to in Asp.Net MVC.

Is there a way to create a single url pattern in Django that will handle "[Application]/view/[params]" in a way similar to Asp.Net MVC? Perhaps at the main web site level?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that it is possible but not advised to do so. I can understand that you want to do it this way (less work ;)) but on the other side you are far more flexible (also in changing URLs) if you specify the URLS and views explicitly.

Comment: I can understand and agree with wanting to separate route definition from classes but if 80% of my routes follow the same convention it would be nice to setup one url pattern for that convention.

Comment: Funny, I came to this question having developed in django previously and the migrating to asp.net. I hate the asp.net implicit routing configuration since I feel I have no control over it... I would really like to do routing django style :)

Comment: @gardarh, did you ever find a way to do .NET MVC routes more like django?  The closest I have found is [MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/) but still not as simple and elegant as django urlconf.

Comment: @RonSmith Not really, just by being more specific when specifying the routes, i.e. don't use the {controller} tag. Not a very beutiful solution imo, please tell if you find anything better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View may not only be function, but also a class.

You can easily specify some kind of DispatchedView class with `__call__` method and dispatch to method according to remaining URI. Also, You can inspire yourself with CherryPy dispatcher.

However, it's considered beter to use named patterns and have URIs and views completely decoupled.

Comment: I've seen CherryPy come up a couple of times in my research on other Python topics. I'll have to read up on it more and see what I can come up with.